# Using apt-get to get specific version of eclipse

Tags: ubuntu

Normally can get eclipse by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

which will install the latest version of eclipse.
But I want eclipse Indigo (or Juno)

Is there a way to decide what version of eclipse I want by using apt-get?

Comment: ¿Maybe changing the repository links?, I usually download it and unzip it directly anyway, best way :-)

Comment: Where do you put them when you download them manually, so that they can be opened when you just type "eclipse" in the shell?

Comment: I usually just unzip it, I go to folder and press enter, I don't do it from shell :-) sorry! hehe but I suppose you can create some other direct command to exec from shell and open the eclipse in the folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide eclipse
```

"umake --help" on 14.04 reports as of writing that this will get you "Pure Eclipse Luna (4.4)"
also see [this](http://thenepalidroidguy.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-install-ubuntu-make-formerly-named-ubuntu-developer-tools-center-in-ubuntu-14.04-14.10.html)
and [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

Comment: Been a while since I posted this. I moved on to IDEA.. but i tried it just now as is above and it worked for me. What happens on your side?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a command like:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform=3.8.1-5.1
```

This will get the same version available through the Ubuntu Software Center, which is 3.8.1-5.1